# SAS: How can you write an IF statement to categorize data before a certain date and after it

Tags: if-statement, sas

I have a table with a column named DATE1 with format YYYY-MM-DD, and I need to create another column to categorize data into two groups. How should I write the code? I think that the problem is with the date format, the syntax should change.

```
    Data Tabla1;
    set &tTable0; 

    if DATE1 < 2001-12-31 THEN DATE1_AUX = "<2001"; else
   DATE1_AUX = >2001;

    keep    Date1
            DATE1_AUX;

    run;
```

Comment: Is `date1` numeric or character? and in your `else` statement `>2001` should be in quotes as `">2001"`.

Comment: Explicitly - is `date1` a SAS date value (so, unformatted, a value like `16143`) or is it a character string [or a numeric representation of a character string], `"2001-05-12"` or similar?  (If you don't understand SAS dates well enough to know that answer, try adding one - `data table1; set &tTable0; new_date = date1+1; run;` - and see if you get a new value that is one day later than the old value, or if you get a complaint in the log about character-numeric conversion and then a missing value in the new_date field.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS stores date values internally as the number of days since January 1, 1960. In other words, to compare two date strings (as to say, categorize one of them) we must first deduce, for each date string, the number of days since January 1, 1960.

Luckily, there are temporal formats and functions that make our lives easier. Here is one solution you could use to categorize a date in the way you describe:

```
data Table0;
    format DATE1 YYMMDD10.; 
    input DATE1 YYMMDD10.;
    cards;
2001-12-30
2001-12-31
2002-01-01
;
run;

data Table1;
    length DATE1_AUX $ 10.;
    set Table0;
    if DATE1 < input('2001-12-31',YYMMDD10.) then DATE1_AUX = '< 2001';
    else                                          DATE1_AUX = "> 2001";
run;
```

Here we must first convert the string `2001-12-31` to a number representing a SAS date before we can use it to compare against.

A different idea that might be applicable would be to make a custom format:

```
proc format;
    value aux_fmt  low - '31DEC31'd  = '< 2001'
                   '01JAN01'd - high = '> 2001';
run;

data Table1;
    set Table0;
    format DATE1 aux_fmt.;
run;
```

Where a new variable is not created, and the `DATE1` stored values are not changed, but the *formatted* presentation of the date in tables and graphs would be categorized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Data Tabla1;
    set &tTable0; 
    if put(DATE1,yymmdd10.)< '2001-12-31' THEN DATE1_AUX = "<2001";
    else DATE1_AUX =">2001";
    keep  Date1 DATE1_AUX;
    run;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it answers the question in a particularly efficient way  and doesn't contain any explanation of how it works.